# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier doesn't alloc?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode4.6

```
MyViewController *myVC = (MyViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

[scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

The above code works, it loads a view controller that I have in my storyboard with the Storyboard ID of: "MyViewController" and displays it as a sub view.

The only thing is that I'd like to, for example, set a UILabel's text on that View Controller BEFORE doing addSubview.

Like this:

```
MyViewController *myVC = (MyViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

myVC.aTextLabel.text = @"pippo";

[scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

However, this does not work. The UILabel is empty. - I can't do anything with the view until AFTER I do addSubview. Like this:

```
MyViewController *myVC = (MyViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

[scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];

myVC.aTextLabel.text = @"pippo";
```

The above works but it isn't pretty, the label's text is changed after the view has been added!

When I used to do this without Storyboards I would do this:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

    myVC.aTextLabel.text = @"pippo";

    [scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

Which would work fine.

The view that I am displaying is not being connected to other views via seque, I am loading multiple instances of it into a UIScrollView, side by side, so I was hoping that the easiest method would be something similar to the above.

So, how can I instantiate the view programmatically, update a UILabel on that view, and then add it as a subview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that although the view controller is created (allocated and initialized), its view hierarchy is not loaded until someone references its view property.

So when you read `myVc.view` (which is really `[myVc view]`), that causes the view controller to load its views from the storyboard if they haven't been loaded already.

You may need to consider your design here. Creating a view controller, just to take its views and add them to some other view hierarchy is not a good idea **unless** you do it within the framework of the container view controller APIs.

Check out "Creating Custom Container View Controllers" [in the View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) if you want to combine several view controllers together on screen at once.

Comment: Having now read that , I am still non the wiser - a container view's view controller doesn't act as a "template" that I can clone. As in my question I'm looking to have multiple view controllers side by side in a scroll view, each view controller will have its own buttons and table view inside of it with a common data source and delegate.

Comment: Well right, if you want to have multiple view controllers active and onscreen at the same time, then that's exactly what container view controllers are designed to do. You would have a container view controller which contains and manages however many other view controllers you need.

Comment: Thank you! - and thank SO for letting us read this, and thank Google for helping us find SO. I would nave never realized this on my own.